# Monitor going black regularly

Tags: macos, display, high-sierra

The monitor connected to my Mac mini is going dark regularly for a few seconds, then he comes back up. What could this be? It is not a flickering, the monitor just loses connection.

- Mac mini (Late 2012)
- macOS High Sierra 10.13.6
- Monitor is a Dell U2713HM
- second monitor which blacks out only very rarely (but he does as well sometimes.)

I have checked the cables about 100x times.

Comment: is the monitor going black maybe do to any power outage? @KSPR

Comment: Are you using an adapter? Try changing it and test. Test the monitor with other computer as well.

Comment: no adapter. no power outage.

Comment: When you say checked the cables, have you tried replacing the cables with new ones? Also what kind of cable is it, older cables may not support the resolution you are trying to run at.

Comment: I didn't exchange the cable. It's a DisplayPort cable. Altough, I have two monitors connected. And sometimes both blackout, but one blacks out far more than the other. The other almost never balcks out.

Comment: Has it always done this, or only recently?

Comment: @unknowndomain pretty much always

Comment: You can try swapping the cables and try swapping the video source i.e. use a different computer.

Comment: "Go dark" as in the brightness goes way down or it turns off?  When you say, "you checked the cables 100x times" what does that mean?  Did you actually swap the cables out with known good ones?

Comment: Thanks guys. As far as I can understand it is probably the cable connection who is unstable. I'll conduct a bit more wiggle tests but I think the port on the mac mini to the cable is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The most common causes for these types of blackouts are poor cables, poorly shielded monitors or excessive environmental noise.

If you have nearby sources of EMI (electromagnetic interference), try moving these sources or the monitor/computer/cable. In practice I have seen for example 4G/LTE hot spots, burglar alarms, stereo receivers and other similar equipment cause blackouts.

The next step is to replace the cables with properly shielded cables of a good quality.

If that doesn't help, contact your the seller of the monitor for support.

Comment: I'm in the attic. There is a massive Solar Array above me. Is it possible this causes interferences? But then on the other hand, everyone on that floor should have this problem which they don't

Comment: Depending on your installation, the solar panels may have micro inverters on the roof which could produce some noise, you can test this by moving away from the roof, or buying some different cables.

Answer (score 2):

Been struggling with this for almost a year, trying out almost all suggestions found here and elsewhere on the 'net (switching cables, using a HDMI adapter, changing the energy settings, screen saver, etc.)

FWIW, what finally worked for me was disabling auto-source selection on the external monitor...

More specifically, for the Samsung LU28E590DS it can be done like this:

**Menu** | **System** | **Source Detection** → *Manual*

Tested with a Mac Mini M1,2020